# How to install grub theme on boot partition?

Tags: grub2, 20.04

How can I move my theme so grub can display it properly. I created a root and a boot partition, and the root partition is encrypted so grub can't access the theme, in my old laptop I had the same setup but I don't remember how I did it. I only remember that I change the grub default file and point to the boot partition instead of the root encrypted partition. Does anyone knows how to do it/ has a tutorial on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: Grub with theme when you have an encrypted root filesystem:
original post: https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/grub-with-a-theme-when-you-have-an-encrypted-root-filesystem/

###### You have to move the theme to the boot partition where encryption is not enabled (and bc of that grub will be able to access the theme). Instructions:

After installing normally your theme:

```
sudo mkdir -p /boot/themes
sudo cp -pr /usr/share/grub/themes/{name-of-theme} /boot/themes
sudo ln -s {name-of-theme} /boot/themes/live
```

Then I adjust `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_THEME=/boot/themes/live/theme.txt
```

Then on the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```